# Proper notation for "unpacking" n-tuples from a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

(I will begin by saying I am unsure if "unpacking", as mentioned in the title, is the correct term for what I am about to describe; I use it since it is the correct term for extracting values from a tuple in programming languages.)

Consider a set of 2-tuples $A = \{(a_0, b_0), (a_1, b_1), \ldots, (a_n, b_n)\}$. What is the proper way to write an expression which references the two elements of any tuple in $A$? For example, would
$$
(\text{some expression involving $x$ and $y$}) \forall (x,y)\in A
$$
be syntactically correct?

Comment: We have to recall that $\forall z (z \in A \leftrightarrow \exists x \exists y (z=(x,y)))$

Comment: Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* (3rd ed.), Theorem 9.8 begins: "Let $\mathbf{f}$ be a $\mathscr{C}'$-mapping of an open set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, such that $\mathbf{f(a, b) = 0}$ for some point $\mathbf{(a, b)} \in E$." Is that an example of the kind of expression you are asking about (leaving aside the identification of $\mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ with $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m$)?

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand the definition of **f** or $E$, but the use of the notation **(a,b)** $\in E$ seems to follow what I suspected might be valid notation in my question.

Comment: How about this example, from [External wreath product with diagonal action - Groupprops](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/External_wreath_product_with_diagonal_action)? "... a pair $(h,k) \in H \times K$ sends $f:S \to G$ to the function $\alpha(k) \circ f \circ \rho(h^{-1})$."

Comment: Your wording "references the two elements of *any* tuple of $A$" is confusing, but if you mean "of *every* tuple" (as suggested by the "$\forall$" in your attempt) and want to form a new set with the results, then the set-builder notation answer is what you want. If that's not what you want, then some clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation):

$$
S=\{x+y\vert (x,y) \in A\}
$$